# What's the grammar of vimrc, how to use variable, function in vimrc?

Tags: function, vim

For some personal reasons, I'd like to customize my vim very detailed. For example, in a specific directory, say "CFxxx", when I create a cpp file, I'd like it to pre-write some template code into my code. But if I was not in that directory, vim works as normal.

As I found on others' vimrc, they define a function, and use filetype to detect cpp files, and use codes like this to add template code:

```
if (expand("%:e") == 'cpp' || expand("%:e") == 'cc')
    call append(line(".")+6, "#include<bits/stdc++.h>")
    call append(line(".")+7, "using namespace std;")
    call append(line(".")+8, "")
endif
```

But that's weaker than what I want. I'd like it to be directory-specific and filetype-specific. I found there's a function getcwd() as a builtin function in vim, which can be used to get the directory, but I don't know how to use it in vimrc. And that's the point.

So what's the grammar of vimrc? Is it a famous programming language? Where  can I learn to write the correct code to customize my vim and solve the above problem.

Comment: To learn vimscript, look at the very good links given on the [SO vim tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vim/info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add to your vimrc:

```
augroup cpp_setup
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType cpp source cpp.vim
augroup END
```

And then create a cpp.vim file, in wich you put

```
" General stuff for all your cpp file
let b:com = '//'

inoremap <buffer> <leader>s std::
inoremap <buffer> <leader>str std::string

" specific stuff for your specific dir
if getcwd() ==# 'diryouwant'
    "Do what you want here, such has:
    set wrap
    call setline('1', "#include <cstdlib>")
endif
```

You will find explanations about those lines (autocommand, conditionnal, function) in this wonderfull tutorial: [learnvimscriptthehardway](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/). Long tuto, but totally worth it.